# Как разрывать запросы на JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, get

**Всем добрый день.**

Есть задача при которой я совершаю несколько GET запросов для получения JSON при определенном действии:

1. Получение из JSON базовой информации
2. Получение вторичной информации

Однако, если я делаю это действие быстро например два раза, то второй запрос начинает выполняться вместе с тем первым, который еще не успел выполниться.

**Как на чистом js или на JQuery сделать сброс всех GET запросов при определенном действии, например нажатие на клавишу?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы при выполнении двух Ajax запросов идущих подряд, второй запрос не начинал выполнение, пока не выполнится первый, просто в параметрах первого запроса укажите: `async: false`

> `async` (default: `true`) (Type: Boolean) - По умолчанию все запросы
>   отправляются асинхронно (т.е. по умолчанию это значение равно `true`).
>   Если вам нужны синхронные запросы, установите для этого параметра
>   значение `false`. Обратите внимание, что синхронные запросы могут временно блокировать браузер, отключая любые действия, пока запрос активен. [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Как одно из решений `async: false` - имеет место быть, но не рекомендуется этого делать по причине подвисания браузера. Смысл Ajax как раз в том, чтобы выполнение было асинхронным, без перезагрузки страницы ну и удобство с быстротой выполнения (AJAX - Asynchronous Javascript and XML). Лучше выполнять так называемые `callback`, чем синхронный запрос.

Можно поместить один запрос внутрь другого. К примеру вам нужно, чтобы второй запрос выполнился в случае успешного завершения первого запроса, тогда поместив внутрь `success` - функции первого запроса второй запрос, вы выполните второй запрос в случае успешного выполнения первого, тогда `async: false` не будет нужен. Вот как пример:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "someurl",
    data: 'somedata',
    success: function (data) {
        var a = data; // результат возвращенный с результате первого запроса

        $.ajax({ // второй запрос
            type: "post",
            url: "someurl",
            data: 'somedata' + a, // просто как пример
            success: function (data) {
                // тут можем еще что-то делать
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Ссылка на источник: [jQuery Ajax Request inside Ajax Request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089580/5275890)

Касаемо остановки запроса - это тоже возможно, просто нужно сохранить результат Ajax запроса в переменную, а затем вызвать метод `abort()` у этой переменной, как вам уже дали ссылку. Вот пример оттуда:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'someurl',
    success: function(result){}
});

// Затем вы можете прервать запрос
request.abort();
```

Ссылка на источник: [Stop all active ajax requests in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802948/5275890)

Comment: `async: false` - очень плохое решение.

Comment: @Suvitruf согласен с вами, что будет подвисать, я написал про временную блокировку. Но как способ - он имеет место быть. Лучше конечно в `done` вызвать функцию, которая будет содержать второй запрос.

Comment: Спасибо, отличный и понятный ответ лайк, однако я скорее всего не совсем корректно сформулировал задачу, с ней я более менее разобрался не без вашей помощи, однако возникла еще одна проблема. https://jsfiddle.net/e8wp8r20/

Comment: @FrogFrogov, пожалуйста, рад, что вам помогло. Я зашел на jsfiddle но не совсем понял, что там у вас не так... Обратил внимание на то, что в переменной `xhr_2` у вас пустая строка, зачем? А еще `$.ajax(...)` возвращает объект `XMLHttpRequest` - думаю вам поможет. И условие  там где `typeof(xhr_2)  == "object"` - я бы переделал. В общем, вам есть чем заняться. Если ответ верный, его отмечают таковым (напротив ответа галочка), а если возник новый вопрос - задайте его (не забудьте прикрепить ваш код и описать проблему) и вам обязательно помогут.